# How to place functions inside tkinter drop down list?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, my purpose with this program is to store, whats displayed on the main frame, inside the drop down list, which shows the list of the rappers. So instead of just being displayed on the main frame, I want it to be hidden until the particular name of the artist (to whom the the picture, play button and stop button belongs to) is picked in the list.
Please help me with this. Thank you.

This is the screenshot of the program atm.
So far there are 4 things displayed on the main frame The list which was made with tkinter, picture, play button and the stop button.

[image]

```
import pygame
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

root.title("Hip-Hop-Flow")
root.iconbitmap("22.ico")
root.geometry("800x600")
pygame.mixer.init()


class Vini:

    def __init__(self):

        self.rappers = ["Vinnie Paz", "Sean Price", "Big L", "Canibus"]
        self.menu = StringVar()
        self.menu.set("List of rappers")

        siis_chamoshla = OptionMenu(root, self.menu, *self.rappers)
        siis_chamoshla.configure(width=30, bg="white")
        siis_chamoshla.pack()

    def vinispicture(self):
        self.vinniephoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("vini.gif"))
        label = Label(image=self.vinniephoto)
        label.pack()

    def play_vinnie(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.load("vinnie flow.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)

    def stop_vinnie(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

    def design(self):
        play_button = Button(root, text="Play", font=("Helvetica", 20),
                             command=self.play_vinnie)
        play_button.pack(pady=20)
        stop_button = Button(root, text="Stop", font=("Helvetica", 20),
                             command=self.stop_vinnie)
        stop_button.pack(pady=20)


pazienza = Vini()
pazienza.vinispicture(), pazienza.play_vinnie(), pazienza.stop_vinnie(), pazienza.design()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a frame to hold the image and the buttons and this frame is initially hidden.

Then associate a function on the `OptionMenu` via `command` option.  The function will be executed whenever option is selected.  Inside that function you can load the corresponding image and song based on the selected artist:

```py
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Hip-Hop-Flow")
root.iconbitmap("22.ico")
root.geometry("800x600")

pygame.mixer.init()


class Player:
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        self.rappers = ["Vinnie Paz", "Sean Price", "Big L", "Canibus"]

        self.menu = tk.StringVar(value="List of rappers")
        siis_chamoshla = tk.OptionMenu(master, self.menu, *self.rappers, command=self.on_selected)
        siis_chamoshla.configure(width=30, bg="white")
        siis_chamoshla.pack()

        # play panel, initially hidden
        self.panel = tk.Frame(master)
        self.image_label = tk.Label(self.panel)
        self.image_label.pack()
        tk.Button(self.panel, text="Play", font="Helvetica 20", command=self.play_song).pack(pady=20)
        tk.Button(self.panel, text="Stop", font="Helvetica 20", command=self.stop_song).pack(pady=20)

    def on_selected(self, artist):
        # assume the image name is <artist_name>.gif
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=artist+".gif")
        self.image_label.configure(image=self.photo)
        # show the panel
        self.panel.pack()
        # assume the song name is <artist_name>.mp3
        pygame.mixer.music.load(artist+".mp3")

    def play_song(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)

    def stop_song(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

pazienza = Player(root)

root.mainloop()
```

*Note that I have used `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *` because wildcard import is not recommended.*

Comment: one more question, please answer. I kind of got lost. what you mean by <artist_name> like should I make a directory for artist or why is artist there please explain.. copying the path directly to self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="vinnie picture.gif") works but your version does not. whenever i remove artist from self.photo artist argument in def parameter just turns gray...... and tell me please what do you mean by artist+ ?

Comment: As I don't know where those images and songs are, so it is just *an example* that *assuming the image and song are named based on the selected name*.  You need to find a way to get the correct path of the image and song.

Comment: `artist` is the selected name.

Comment: images and songs are in the same directory as everything else. 
https://ibb.co/VCQ9fWW ...  this version without + operator works ""vinnie picture.jpg" , but with + operator it does not....just tell me this, should i remove the artist from here --> def on_selected(self, artist): ..

Comment: No it is a required argument (store the selected name) for the callback of `command` option of `OptionMenu`.  Also hard-coded the image and song name will show the same picture and play the same song no matter which name is selected.  As I said, you need to find a way to get the correct image and song based on the selected name.

Comment: I don't understand how to find that way because i dont see a logic behind self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=artist+"jpg"). but anyways, thank you for your time.

Comment: `artist+".gif"` will be "Vinnie Paz.gif" if "Vinnie Paz" is selected.  It will be "Sean Price.gif" if "Sean Price" is selected, etc.